# php - removing elements from an array that have duplicates values on a specified key

Tags: php, arrays

if i have an array like this :

```
Array (
  [0]=>
  Array (
    ["id"]=> "1"
    ["desc"]=> "desc 1"
    ["type"]=> "T"
    ["date"]=> "17-JAN-12"
  )
  [1]=>
  Array (
    ["id"]=> "2"
    ["desc"]=> "desc 2"
    ["type"]=> "P"
    ["date"]=> "05-JAN-12"
  )
  [2]=>
  Array (
    ["id"]=> "1"
    ["desc"]=> "desc 3"
    ["type"]=> "P"
    ["date"]=> "15-JAN-12"
  )
  [3]=>
  Array (
    ["id"]=> "3"
    ["desc"]=> "desc 4"
    ["type"]=> "P"
    ["date"]=> "06-JAN-12"
  )
  [4]=>
  Array (
    ["id"]=> "2"
    ["desc"]=> "desc 5"
    ["type"]=> "T"
    ["date"]=> "06-JAN-12"
  )
 )
```

I want to remove from it  the elements that has duplicate values on only the key "id" , 
and get :

```
Array (
  [0]=>
  Array (
    ["id"]=> "1"
    ["desc"]=> "desc 1"
    ["type"]=> "T"
    ["date"]=> "17-JAN-12"
  )
  [1]=>
  Array (
    ["id"]=> "2"
    ["desc"]=> "desc 2"
    ["type"]=> "P"
    ["date"]=> "05-JAN-12"
  )
  [2]=>
  Array (
    ["id"]=> "3"
    ["desc"]=> "desc 4"
    ["type"]=> "P"
    ["date"]=> "06-JAN-12"
  )
 )
```

Thanks.

Comment: This task is not so hard. Have you tried something?

Comment: How do you want to handle duplicates? Pick first? Average? Sum? Count?

Comment: which element you take if is duplicated ? the first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $arr){
   if(!isset($result[$arr["id"]])){
      $result[$arr["id"]] = $arr;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems, that `id` is your *primary* key. so loop through array and insert element to new array only if `id` doesn't still exists.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($old_array as $entry) {
    if (empty($new_array[$entry['id']])) $new_array[$entry['id']] = $entry;
}
$new_array = array_values($new_array);
```

btw. the last line is only for re-order your keys in final array